# call a web service after terminating the ios app

Tags: ios, objective-c, web-services

i want call a web service for 10 seconds interval after **terminating** the app, here i need to get the data from the DB for 10 seconds interval. In android they having a service concept to getting a data for particular time interval.

help me.

Comment: iOS does not support running any such things once app is killed. What you can do rather is to initiate the communication from server rather than from client and can send out silent notifications to device and make device fetch data once it receives the notification.

Comment: you can call a webservice in background when app is launch..

Answer (score 0):

You can do it using background Fetch. You need to refer [this](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/BackgroundExecution/BackgroundExecution.html).  This is Apple document for the downloading content in backgrounder mode. As per the **Apple's Document** :

> Apps moving to the background are expected to put themselves into a quiescent state as quickly as possible so that they can be suspended by the system. If your app is in the middle of a task and needs a little extra time to complete that task, it can call the beginBackgroundTaskWithName:expirationHandler: or beginBackgroundTaskWithExpirationHandler: method of the UIApplication object to request some additional execution time. Calling either of these methods delays the suspension of your app temporarily, giving it a little extra time to finish its work. Upon completion of that work, your app must call the endBackgroundTask: method to let the system know that it is finished and can be suspended.

Here is Good tutorial for the background fetch: [Link](https://mobiforge.com/design-development/using-background-fetch-ios)

Follow the tutorial for downloading content in background mode.

Comment: hi iPR we can get the data when the app background but the app is terminated means how we get the data

Comment: @TestiOS you can see that demo in second given link.

Comment: in that example it gives data when app goes background only.after i killed or terminate the app it does not gives any data

Comment: once i killed the app this not gives any data

Comment: Have you visited the link given in the ans? @TestiOS

Comment: In that link apple said that "For tasks that require more execution time to implement, you must request specific permissions to run them in the background without their being suspended. In iOS, only specific app types are allowed to run in the background:" and in it they state that "Background fetch :The app regularly downloads and processes small amounts of content from the network."

Comment: and if app is suspended then you are not able to do any thing just because apple restricts it.